# Pingdom external service format

Tags: pingdom, logentries

I am trying to send alert from Logentries to  Pingdom. Logentries support webhooks and Pingdom can integrate with External Services. Based on http://royal.pingdom.com/2015/02/10/integrate-nagios-pingdom/ I have figured out that it is possible to send data using

```
POST https://anonymous:anonymous@api.pingdom.com/api/3.0/ims.incidents?triggerid=SERVICE_ID&source=service&data_type=nagios&data={}
```

The problem is that I can't find any documentation regarding this endpoint. I'd like to use other than nagios data_type but I can't find which types and formats are supported.

Comment: Have you seen the repo yet? https://github.com/Pingdom/pingdom_nagios/blob/master/pingdom_nagios.py#L45